# jQuery plugin if object exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I use this inside my scripts:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['title-numeric-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    var x = a.match(/title="*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1];
    var y = b.match(/title="*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1];
    x = parseFloat( x );
    y = parseFloat( y );
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};
```

datatableExt comes from this:
http://datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.js

Sometimes i include "jquery.dataTables.js" sometimes I don't.
So I want to add this plugin if datatables code is included.
How can I check?
Is it something like `(typeof fn.dataTableExt != 'undefined')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's as simple as

```
if (!$.fn.dataTableExt) {
    alert('does not exist');
} else {
    alert('does exist');
}
```

Comment: That's correct. In this case, the `typeof` check is unnecessary, because we're checking for a property on an object, not whether a variable exists. (just to clarify why this works)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, right, we just care that the dataTableExt exists, we don't care about the type or value, just that it's there.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you check to see if the Google repository of JQuery has loaded or not:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

but instead it will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if (!$.fn.dataTableExt) { document.write('<script src="http://datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.js"><\/script>')}</script>
```

Comment: don't you mean `if (!$.fn.dataTableExt)...`?

Comment: no, he said that if the function existed, he wanted the plugin to be added.  If that function doesn't exist, then he doesn't need the js file attached

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question though.  I though he was looking for a function on the specific page to decide whether or not to add the library plugin  - fixed top :-)

Comment: I read it as the dataTableExt method as existing inside the script, so he wanted to load it if it wasn't loaded...?

Comment: Thank you opanitch for interest. CaffGeek's solution is what I needed :)